# How to make slices in MPAndroid pie chart a gradient?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

How do I make the slices in an MPAndroid pie chart a gradient?

I see the methods:

```
dataset.setGradientColor
dataset.setGradientColors
```

But I'm not sure how to use them.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding two colors for a single gradient:

```
 dataSet.setGradientColor(Color.WHITE,Color.LTGRAY);  //Start and End Colors
```

Adding multiple colors as a single gradient:

```
List<GradientColor> gradientColors=new ArrayList<>();
                gradientColors.add(new GradientColor(Color.BLUE,Color.parseColor("FFFFFF")));
                gradientColors.add(new GradientColor(Color.WHITE,Color.BLUE));
                gradientColors.add(new GradientColor(Color.BLUE,Color.LTGRAY));
                dataSet.setGradientColors(gradientColors);
```

Comment: When I tried this it just showed a light blue color. No linear gradient was added.

Comment: Try it with different colors. I only wanted to show you how it's supposed to be done and didn't actually care about the colors.

Comment: I tried it with my own colors and it still didn't work.